# How to replace a placeholders from a text with input fields and bind them with v-model with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an exam page with test questions. The questions are from "fill in the gaps" type. I got the questions from ajax request. The questions are simple text with specific placeholders for the places where the "fill in the gap" should be. The questions can have one or more "fill in the gap".

Here is an example:
`The apples are {green} or {red}, some times {yellow}.`

This should be converted to `<p>The apples are <input type='text' v-model='gap1'> or <input type='text' v-model='gap2'>, some times <input type='text' v-model='gap3'>`.

So far I have managed to use them in my component with a computed value:

```
computed: {
    addGapsField () {
        let reg = /\{.*?\}/g
        let mtch = ''
        let text = this.question

        // loop through each match
        while((mtch = reg.exec(text)) !== null) {
            text = text.replace(mtch[0],"<input type='text'>")
        }
        return text 
    }
}
```

How can I bind a v-model to this dynamically generate input fields. Or is there any other way around  (v-model is not the necessary solution i'm looking for, I'm not much familiar with what other options do Vue.js has).

Comment: If you want to create your template dynamic,you need to use render function  to do that ,see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Comment: I thought this was a fun question. Here is some code from me just playing around with it. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VxgOjg?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can possibly split your question into an array and iterate with a `v-for` inside the template (but you need to use `<span>` for an inline display)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    question: "The apples are {green} or {red}, some times {yellow}.",
    gaps: [],
    last: ''
  },
  computed: {
    addGapsField () {
      let reg = /\{.*?\}/g
      let text = this.question.split(reg)
      text.forEach((part, i) => {
        this.gaps.push('gap' + (i+1))
      })
      this.last = text.pop()
      return text
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span v-for="(part, index) in addGapsField">
    {{ part }}<input v-model="gaps[index]">
  </span>
  <span>{{ last }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution @sovalina. Thank you for all the effort for building the code snippet.

Comment: I had to edit sligthly your code. There was a bug caused from the `splice(0,-1)` and the computed properties. The bug was that once you enter any string in the input fields then the last element from the array generated from the `addGapsField` would be removed. I add my implementation which fixed the bug. Thanks again for the code.